# Server Error in '/' Application. Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, exception

I'm currently updating my project (ASP.net C#). Everything is working locally as far as Clean ,Build and Publish Website. When uploading the files to the server for production, I'm getting an error message and can't fix .

Below is the message. Can someone help so i can publish it on my server?

```
Sequence contains more than one element 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOp`enter code here`erationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +5876344
   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +490
   Sinai.Ors.Domain.Repositories.UserRepository.GetUser(String mnemonic) in \\mdpointfs\md\moupar\Public Desktop\ORSUPDATE\Sinai (2)12.22.2014 VS2010\Sinai\Sinai.Ors.Domain\Repositories\UserRepository.cs:19
   SinaiMasterPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContai`enter code here`ner) +186
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +291
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeS`enter code here`tagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098

________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212
```

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace tells you *exactly* where the error is.  In the `GetUser()` method there is a call to `SingleOrDefault()` on a collection.  The collection has more than one element, so the exception is thrown.

The code is assuming that there will never be more than one element in the collection, and that assumption is false for that data.  You have a few options:

1. The data is bad, correct it.  If the data *shouldn't* be in this state then somewhere there is a missing data integrity check.  A unique constraint on a column or set of columns, a foreign key relationship, etc.  It's possible that the schema might not be able to maintain this particular measure of data integrity, in which case the application code should enforce it.
2. If there should be only one record, enforce that.  Check the `Count()` of the collection and if it's greater than 1 then handle that error condition.  Show a message to the user?  Notify somebody?  That's up to you.
3. If it's ok that there is more than one record and you only want the first one, use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `SingleOrDefault()`.

Either way, the stack trace is telling you where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect that an `GetUser()` can have multiple values? If not, `SingleOrDefault` might have shown you an inconsistency. Then you should fix your bug that caused it and stay with it `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

`SingleOrDefault` throws an exception if more than one element exists.

Here you can see exactly what the single or default method does: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault(v=vs.100).aspx`